# Eclipse Jetty Issue: WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext - java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid code lengths set

Tags: eclipse, jetty

Eclipse with run-jetty-run suddenly starts to fail with the message:

```
2014-05-09 13:31:08.360:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/,[file:~/api-public/src/main/webapp/]}
    java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid code lengths set
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:164)
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(ZipInputStream.java:193)
    at java.util.jar.JarInputStream.read(JarInputStream.java:207)
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.closeEntry(ZipInputStream.java:139)
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.getNextEntry(ZipInputStream.java:117)
    at java.util.jar.JarInputStream.getNextEntry(JarInputStream.java:142)
    at java.util.jar.JarInputStream.getNextJarEntry(JarInputStream.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JarScanner.matched(JarScanner.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.PatternMatcher.matchPatterns(PatternMatcher.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.PatternMatcher.match(PatternMatcher.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JarScanner.scan(JarScanner.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaInfConfiguration.preConfigure(MetaInfConfiguration.java:78)
    at runjettyrun.webapp.RJRMetaInfoConfiguration.preConfigure(RJRMetaInfoConfiguration.java:14)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.preConfigure(WebAppContext.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:453)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at runjettyrun.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:80)
```

Things done to try to fix:

- Delete de workspace and regenerate
- Reinstall eclipse
- Reimport the maven project

Eclipse Kepler SR2 + run-jetty-run

Comment: Have you tried **Eclipse -> Project -> Clean** and redeploy&restart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite weird.

I changed the run-jetty server version from 8 to 7 and the error changed to a maven library dependency.

I deleted this library from my local maven repository (.m2/repositories/...), reinstalled and now is working perfectly.